# How Can I add a start-up script to an existing ai notebook instance on google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcloud

I know how to do it when I create an instance:

```
gcloud compute instances create ${INSTANCE_NAME} \
  --machine-type=n1-standard-8 \
  --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email \
  --min-cpu-platform="Intel Skylake" \
  ${IMAGE} \
  --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
  --boot-disk-size=100GB \
  --boot-disk-type=pd-ssd \ 
  --accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1 \
  --boot-disk-device-name=${INSTANCE_NAME} \
  --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --restart-on-failure \
  --metadata="proxy-user-mail=${GCP_LOGIN_NAME},install-nvidia-driver=True,startup-script=${STARTUP_SCRIPT}"
```

but what if I already have an instance, how do I update/create the startup script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add or update the metadata, you can use the endpoint ["add-metadata"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#gcloud) like this

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${INSTANCE_NAME} \
  --metadata startup-script=${NEW_STARTUP_SCRIPT}
```

The other metadatas are kept.

Comment: How can I see the script on a notebook instance? How can I see its output? It is run on every reset, not only in creation, right? thanks.

Comment: The startup scrip is simply a metadata on the Compute Engine. You can read it with a simple [GET request to the metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#querying). For the output, you can either have a look to the serial port console, or I personally redirect the output in a log file (`command >stdout.log 2>stderr.log`) And Yes, it's run at each reset, or you can use a [specific command to trigger again the startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript)

Comment: Thanks! I have this script: "papermill /tutorials/README.ipynb /tutorials/outputrony.ipynb" and I have the README file in the /tutorials directory, but I don't see any output notebook after the instance is started. How can I know I pass the right notebook's path to the papermill script?

Comment: With the startup script,  you run your script with the ROOT user. And the path definition isn't the same as with your own user. Provide the full path of papermill binary to be sure that the startup script find it!

Comment: So I should also find the full path of the notebooks? I tried some things but couldn't get it. Any idea how I can get the full path of the notebooks and papermill? I changed the start-up script to 'mkdir test' and couldn't find a 'test' folder.

Comment: The default $HOME folder is `/root` and you can't write in it. It's normal if you don't find it!! Try `mkdir /tmp/test`. About papermill and your notebooks, I don't know where you stored them. I usually use the linux command `find / -name "papermill" 2>/dev/null`. I hope this helps!!

Comment: My problem is that when I run the notebook using the startup script, the working directory is '/' and also os.path.abspath('') returns '/'. Any idea how I can get the path of the file without using papermill parameters?